# why need a viewcomponent if service injection in view works the same

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am confused about view components and service injection in view.
for eg I have created a method in my repo which returns the count of students.
I can simply inject this service into multiple views.
The same thing can also be achieved with the view component
in both cases we don't depend on the controller.
service can also be called from views along with parameters from any view.
so what explicit benefit does the view component gives over service injection in a view?

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of viewcomponent is not in comparison with controller. It exists to provide a view superior to partial views. This is a part of [introduction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#view-components).

> View components don't use model binding, and only depend on the data
> provided when calling into it...

ViewComponent cannot replace the controller, the controller is for the entire application, and the ViewComponent is only for multiple repetitive sections. It can only be used as a good supplement.

Perhaps, there will not be too many ViewComponents in an application. This is the mianly purpose.

> Razor components are designed for developer productivity when providing client-side UI logic and composition.

Comment: thanks for the answer but you didn't really tell anything about service injection in  the view?service doesn't have anything to do with controller.